# установка graph-tool в PyCharm через Docker

Tags: python, docker, pycharm

скачал докер образ Graph-Tool. В PyCharm поставил удаленный интерпретатор Docker :
Remote Python 3.6.5 Docker (tiagopeixoto/graph-tool:latest). Теперь мне нужно докачать еще пакеты которые необходимы для работы. Предполагаю что нужно на основе образа tiagopeixoto/graph-tool получить новый образ в котором будут установлены все нужные мне пакеты и затем его указать в PyCharm, но как это сделать ?

Answer (score 0):

1. `$ docker exec -it my_containers_name /bin/bash`
2. `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`
3. `python get-pip.py`

Дальше установить нужные пакеты:

```
pip install <name_package>
```

Comment: Ты же потеряешь все изменения при перезапуске контейнера, почему не собрать свой кастомный образ на основе `graph-tool:latest` с установленными пакетами?

Comment: хорошее замечание, учту, спасибо